# Spring: How to combine @RestClientTest with a RestTemplate with @Qualifier?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, qualifiers

I have changed a Spring Boot (2.1.4) service that consumes a `RestTemplate` to use a `@Qualifier`. Now my Test (with `@RestClientTest` and `@AutoConfigureWebClient`) fails because it can not resolve the bean.

How do I fix this?

The config:

```
  @Bean
  @Qualifier("eureka")
  @LoadBalanced
  RestTemplate eurekaRestTemplate() {
```

The service:

```
  public ClarkClient(
      @Qualifier("eureka") RestTemplate restTemplate, ClarkConfiguration configuration)
      throws URISyntaxException {
```

The test:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
@RestClientTest({CastorClient.class, CastorConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)
class CastorClientWebTest {

  @Autowired
  private CastorClient cut;

  @Autowired
  private MockRestServiceServer server;
```

The error:

```
[2019-04-16T14:02:22,614] [WARN ] [            ....AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] [refresh 557] : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'castorClient' defined in file [/home/martinsc/java/routing/route-testing-batch-manager/out/production/classes/com/tyntec/routetesting/batchmanager/core/clients/CastorClient.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=eureka)}
```

Comment: annotate `CastorClientWebTest` with `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: @Deadpool Nope, that explodes very loudly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution that worked for me: `@AutoConfigureWebClient` (without `(registerRestTemplate = true)`). 
In the `@TestConfiguration` class create a bean of `RestTemplate` with the right `@Qualifier`

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("eureka")
public RestTemplate eurekaRestTemplate() {
  return new RestTemplate();
}
```

Inject that into the test class

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("eureka")
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Now we need to wire that into the `MockRestServiceServer`. We do that via `@BeforeEach`

```
private MockRestServiceServer server;
@BeforeEach
  void setUp () {
    server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You should not use `(registerRestTemplate = true)` as it will create a RestTemplate bean for you which is not the one you use.

If your qualified RestTemplate bean is declared in your `CastorConfiguration`, try using `@Import(CastorConfiguration.class)`

Comment: Nope. The config class is `RestTemplateConfig` and simply importing that doesn't help. How would I declare my own `RestTemplate` for use with `@RestClientTest`? I already have `@TestConfiguration` class in the test class.